# Как ввести выходные данные для приложения "Поиск последнего созданного файла с заданным расширением":

Tags: c#, visual-studio, консоль

Дано такое задание:
Разработать консольное приложение "Поиск последнего созданного файла с заданным расширением":

```
 Входные данные: путь к папке и расширение файла

 Выходные данные: самый последний по дате создания файл заданного расширения. Если в директории несколько файлов с заданным расширением, то результатом должен быть самый "свежий" файл +  список файлов дата создания которых отличается от этого файла не более чем на 10 секунд.
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FileSearch
{
    public class Program
    {
        public void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Путь:");
            string path = Console.ReadLine();
            if (Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Введите расширение");
                string type = Console.ReadLine();

                var result = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, type);
                foreach (var m in result)
                    Console.WriteLine(m);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No directory!");
            }

            new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles().OrderByDescending(o => o.LastWriteTime).FirstOrDefault();

        }

    }   
}
```

---

1. Я пробовала написать вывод последнего по дате создания файла заданного расширения через, но не уверена в правильно использования такого формата

> new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles().OrderByDescending(o =>
>   o.LastWriteTime).FirstOrDefault()

2.Как прописать выходные данные с условием (понимаю,что скорее всего через конструктор if..else,но как именно,хотелось бы узнать

> Если в директории несколько файлов с заданным расширением, то
>   результатом должен быть самый "свежий" файл +  список файлов дата
>   создания которых отличается от этого файла не более чем на 10 секунд.

Comment: приложите код текстом, а не скриншотом. И опишите подробней вашу проблему, и как вы пытались её решить.

Comment: На первый вопрос: 1. Почему эта строка отдельно от всего кода? Почему она например не внутри проверки на наличие директории? 2. Вы получили некоторые данные, но вы их не присваиваете куда либо для дальнейшей работы, смысл тогда вообще в этой строке (добавьте `var result =` в начало хотя бы)? 3. Вы берете все файлы, а по заданию вам надо получить только с определенным расширением. У `GetFiles()` есть возможность использовать строку поиска (что то вроде `GetFiles("*.txt")`, используйте как минимум ее. 4. `последнего по дате`, логичней будет переделать так, что бы в конце было `.LastOrDefault()`.

Comment: Спасибо!Я сразу написала, что скорее всего написано все с ошибками, я учу c# вторую неделю и пока мне все даётся нелегко, поэтому прошу прощения, если кому-то вопрос показался глупым:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я увидел, что вам уже ответили, но я всё же решил сделать полный ответ. Вот я написал короткий код, который хорошо работает (если что, я сортировал их не по дате изменения, а по дате создания):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace LastCreatedFileSearcher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filePath, fileType;

            Console.Write("Путь: ");
            filePath = Console.ReadLine();

            if (Directory.Exists(filePath))
            {
                Console.Write("Расширение: ");
                fileType = Console.ReadLine();

                var foundFiles = new DirectoryInfo($"{filePath}").GetFiles($"*.{fileType}");

                if (foundFiles.Length > 0)
                {
                    foundFiles = foundFiles.OrderByDescending(file => file.CreationTime).ToArray();
                    var lastCreatedFile = foundFiles.First();
                    foundFiles = foundFiles.TakeWhile(file => lastCreatedFile.CreationTime - file.CreationTime <= new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10)).ToArray();

                    for (int i = 0; i < foundFiles.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (i == 1) Console.WriteLine("Файлы, созданные в ближайшие 10 сек после последнего созданного:");
                        Console.WriteLine($"{i+1}. Имя файла: {foundFiles[i].Name} | Дата создания: {foundFiles[i].CreationTime}");                        
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Файлов с расширением '.{fileType}' в директории не существует");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Директории не существует");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Я не буду повторяться про **GetFiles(string)** и т.д., а укажу на некоторые другие маленькие ошибки **в стиле кода**. Они не так важны, тем более раз вы только начинаете изучать C#, однако в будующем эти советы вам, возможно, пригодятся (если кто то не согласен, поправьте меня):

- Именуйте переменные более корректно, например: не **result**, а более корректно было бы назвать **foundFiles**, не **o**, а **file** и т.д.
- Перед конструкцией **if** обычно оставляют пустую строку
- **Путь** и **расширение** вы написали по-русски, а **No directory** - по-английски

Comment: спасибо огромное!!! Все предельно понятно стало!

Comment: а можно тебе задать еще вопросы, если не затруднит,кончено?

Comment: да, почему бы нет, но если что, я им постоянно учусь и тоже могу ошибаться)) если что, вот моя телега @kuzcode